Refereeing for American Journal Experts
I was asked via mail (which looks borderline suspicious) to referee a paper for the American Journal Experts AJE, who claim to coordinate the refereeing for a Hindawi journal dedicated to applied mathematics. They offer 50$ for it so I am tempted to apply.

I have a manuscript that I believe fits with your expertise. Would you consider reviewing this manuscript for potential publication in a scientific journal? The title and abstract of this manuscript are provided below. We offer an optional $50 honorarium for a completed evaluation.
We ask that you complete your review within 4-5 days so that we can return your comments to the authors of the paper quickly. Please let me know if you will need more time by indicating a new due date with your reply. Reasonable extensions can be accommodated in most cases.
If you would like to recommend a colleague to review this manuscript, please respond with their name and email address. We'll send them an invitation if they meet our reviewer criteria.

Has anyone experience with that? Is this a serious thing?

We ask that you complete your review within 4-5 days... I understand that these things can be field-dependent, but for me this alone implies immediate binning.

I was able to haggle for two weeks. Nonetheless, even though it's paid, I still have a bad feeling about this.

"the refereeing for a Hindawi journal" Well, it's of course everybody's own choice what to think of certain journals or publishers. For me, the sentence that I quoted would suffice press to the delete button.

To add they can't show the article before I agree and the paper does not seem to be on arXiv (weird). I decided to reject it. Thank you for your input.

I see the matter is now settled, but let me anyway elaborate on what I said before: even if they agree to give you two weeks (or two months) to review a particular paper, the fact that they pressure reviewers to do the job within 5 days is a clear sign to me that they are not interested in meaningful peer review.

Hindawi and paying $50 for reviewing means its a scam sorry

$50 was cheap for your soul.

@LazzaroCampeotti statistics indicate that reviewers take a median of 5 hours (mean of 9 hours) to complete reviews - https://www.stm-assoc.org/2012_12_11_STM_Report_2012.pdf (page 36). Granted, things might be different in applied math.

The request itself is highly unusual - AJE is not supposed to be doing peer review, they only do editing (based on their website). Besides, they are not the journal, so they can't be inviting reviewers for the journal. I would guess that if this is a real invitation, then they're doing pre-submission review, i.e. the main questions they want answered are about structure, language, whether the target journal is appropriate, and so on (which is also why their email says "... potential publication in a scientific journal" and not "our scientific journal".)

Given that this kind of editing is much easier than peer review, I don't see why not do it if the $50 matters to you, but you might want to confirm what exactly it is that is expected.

@Allure reviews for math papers have notoriously long turn around times. Some of that is cultural procrastination, but a good bit of it is also due to the janitor work of attempting to validate the correctness of proofs.

Did they ask for your bank account number to send the payment...?

If interested, I discussed my experience in "working" for AJE in comments to this Academia answer. (Quotes used because, after being one of their freelance editors for a few months and not editing a single paper, I asked them to remove my name from consideration for editing.)

@Allure: I expect that in math (including applied math) the time spent by reviewers is substantially longer than in sciences in general. But aside from that, my interpretation of the document you link is that reviewers spend a median of 5 hours actually doing the review . If you ask me to do something on a random day, the chances that I will have 5 hours to devote to it over the next 4-5 days are essentially zero.

@LazzaroCampeotti then you should decline to perform the review. Still, someone else might conceivably be able to spare 5 hours in the next 4-5 days, so I think the conclusion they are not interested in meaningful peer review is too strong.
